# Notation for functions returning dependent types

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I was writing some pseudocode, and wanted to specify that the function type `Combinator` that has an associated arity which is the same as the first `Int` argument:

```
F :: Int -> List<Int> -> Combinator
```

I was thinking that if I had some way of writing a dependent type, then I could write some psuedocode like this:

```
F :: List<Int> -> (Int(a) -> Combinator<a>)
-- or even
F :: Int(a) -> List<Int> -> Combinator<a>
```

How should I express this? Is there any established notation for specifying that a function returns a dependent type of its argument?

Comment: You could look at the syntax of languages with dependent types like Agda, Idirs, etc. I'd suggest `f :: (a :: Int) -> ... -> Combinator<a>` or `f :: forall (a :: Int) -> ... -> Combinator<a>`. I believe I saw some mock-up of dependent Haskell using the `forall (a :: T) -> ....` syntax.

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://langdev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

In Idris the spelling is

```
F : (arity : Int) -> List Int -> Combinator arity
```

https://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#dependent-types